TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'None')
I'm building this simple Kanban board using Angular's drag and drop CDK  Earlier today it was working fine, but now all I'm getting a blank screen, the console shows:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'None') at common.mjs:3066:33
My code is pretty much a copy paste of the Angular's code.
HTML:
<main>
    <div class="boardWrapper">
        <div class="example-container">
            <h2>To do</h2>

            <div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
                class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                @for (item of todo; track item) {
                <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="example-container">
            <h2>Done</h2>

            <div cdkDropList #doneList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="done" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
                class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                @for (item of done; track item) {
                <div class="example-box" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</main>


TS
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CdkDragDrop,
  moveItemInArray,
  transferArrayItem,
  CdkDrag,
  CdkDropList,
  CdkDragHandle
} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-board',
  templateUrl: './board.component.html',
  styleUrl: './board.component.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CdkDropList, CdkDrag, CdkDragHandle],
})
export class BoardComponent {
  todo = ['Get to work', 'Pick up groceries', 'Go home', 'Fall asleep'];

  done = ['Get up', 'Brush teeth', 'Take a shower', 'Check e-mail', 'Walk dog'];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
    }
  }



}

This is the part the console is highlighting with the error, but I don't know what to make of it:
**static {
this.ɵdir = /* @__PURE__ */i0.ɵɵdefineDirective({
  type: NgClass,
  selectors: [["", "ngClass", ""]],
  inputs: {
    klass: [i0.ɵɵInputFlags.None, "class", "klass"],
    ngClass: "ngClass"
  },
  standalone: true
});

}**
I'm running Angular 17
Searched on internet and stack overflow but the solutions are all related to the specific OP's problem, not general.

There is no reference to "none" in the code provided. Somewhere common.mjs seems to be attempting to read the property "none" of some object, but said object doesn't exist.

Try to use Getters for the variables like todo,done. e.g.
get Todo(){     return this.todo;   }

Edited the original post to show the part with the highlighted error

So then i0.ɵɵInputFlags doesn't exist. What do you expect it to be?

I honestly have no idea, I've been using Angular for 2 months so your question is way beyond my knowledge.

Are any errors/warnings output in the console when you run ng build?

No errors/warnings, it builds normally

I was able to solve it, I was running the latest CDK version that was uploaded 5 days ago. I uninstalled the package and installed the previous version, everything is working fine now.
